# Guzzle Async Multiple Promises

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

So I'm trying to use guzzle for a couple of concurrent requests. I've seen several examples online and this is what I came up with, but can't seem to get it to work. No errors, no warnings, nothing. I've tried logging inside each promise but nothing happens.

And I know for sure that nothing is happening because nothing is getting inserted in the DB. Any ideas what I'm missing? (I'm yielding each request with its respective `then` because at the end of each promise, the DB operations are specific to that user)

```php
use GuzzleHttp\Promise\EachPromise;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

$promises = (function () use($userUrls){
    $userUrls->each(function($user) {
        yield $this->client->requestAsync('GET', $user->pivot->url)
            ->then(function (ResponseInterface $response) use ($user) {
                $this->dom->load((string)$response->getBody());
                // ... some db stuff that inserts row in table for this
                // $user with stuff from this request
            });
    });
});

$all = new EachPromise($promises, [
    'concurrency' => 4,
    'fulfilled' => function () {

    },
]);

$all->promise()->wait();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure wht you don't get an error, but your generator is definitely wrong.

```
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use function GuzzleHttp\Promise\each_limit_all;

$promises = function () use ($userUrls) {
    foreach ($userUrls as $user) {
        yield $this->client->getAsync($user->pivot->url)
            ->then(function (ResponseInterface $response) use ($user) {
                $this->dom->load((string)$response->getBody());
                // ... some db stuff that inserts row in table for this
                // $user with stuff from this request
            });
    };
};

$all = each_limit_all($promises(), 4);

$all->promise()->wait();
```

Note `foreach` instead of `$userUrls->each()`, it's important because in your version generator function is the function that is passes to `->each()` call, not the one you assign to `$promise`.

Also note that you must activate the generator (call `$promises()` as pass the result, not pass the function itself to Guzzle).

Otherwise all looks good, try the code with my changes.